# SQL Server index with few values

Tags: sql, indexing

I have mid-sized database with around 100 GB, it contains the main table, and few foreign tables. I have few indices on this main table.

My question is, one of the columns I use in WHERE clause could contain only 8 values, from 0-7, as the values are few, is it effective a create an index for this column or it's just waste of storage?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless there is a big skew in the distribution of the 8 values, you are probably better off looking elsewhere. Which RDBMS?

Comment: As with indexes generally, it depends how you are using the table.  There would seem to be no inherent reason not to index, but without more information, it is difficult to be certain.

Comment: well, mainly I use many indices to search for my data, like data time, stc.., but I use this specific column mainly for GROUP BY clause, and WHERE clause. for the 8 values, 4 values are commonly used, others are rarely.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large table (many rows), then narrowing a search to one-eighth of the rows is something well worth doing. What will improve upon that is to have another field that can narrow it down even further. So if your `where` clause has `where Field1 = 4 and Field2 = x`, then creating the index with both Field1 and Field2 will help. Even if Field2 also has only possible 8 values, now you've narrow the search to one-sixty-fourth of the table (assuming, of course, that each value occurs with about the same probability).

In your case, that assumption doesn't seem to hold, at least for Field1, but that would still be 4 * 8 = 32 segments to search instead of one.

Perform timing tests to get some actual figures to compare. That is really the only way to determine how much an index improves performance or even if it actually improves it at all.

These are general answers but without more details, that about all we can give you.